# What are particle settings for water spray simulation?

Tags: texturing, materials, particles, shaders, fluid-simulation

I was trying to recreate some scenes from James Cameron's Titanic. I wanted to make this scene look like the ship displaces water and throws water splash particles. I have used fluid simulation for now. Could someone suggest to me particle settings or the way to do it to achieve the result?

Also please don't suggest flip fluids as it will kill me.

My Render:
[image]

The result I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the physics properties for the Domain, under particle you need to check some combination of Spray, Foam, and Bubbles; and then experiment with the settings to get the result you want.  I can't tell you specific value for settings, because that would depend on the look and lighting you want.

Make sure you change the type to Modular or All before you bake.

[image: particle settings]